how do I get a numbered equation inline?
This is a tricky one that I didn't manage to get right.
I have some text followed by an equation environment. I want to include it so that the equation is numbered and can be referred to, however, I don't want to have a line break and spacing, it should be more like an inline equation that continues the current line.
I am not sure how to do that.
Here is MWE that doesn't do that right
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation environment

\begin{document}

Then, we define:

\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}


\end{document}

I want something naturally latex that looks more like:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equation environment

\begin{document}

Then, we define: $x=y \quad\quad (1)$

\end{document}

